# Why python logging module rotating day log mess up?

Tags: python, logging, logrotate

I want to rotate two log files by day in python2.7, uWSGI, master/worker, multiple processes. I wrote a common logger named logger.py.

```
import yaml

import logging, logging.config
log_conf = yaml.load(open('logger.yaml'))
logging.config.dictConfig(log_conf)

logger = logging.getLogger('access')
exc_logger = logging.getLogger('exception')
```

The other modules write logs like this.

```
from logger import logger, exc_logger
...
logger.error('Req index error | err=%s', e)
exc_logger.exception('Req index error')
```

Here is the configuration file logger.yaml.

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:
    simple:
        format: '%(asctime)s | %(name)8s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s'
        datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    detailed:
        format: '%(asctime)s | %(process)d | %(levelname)s | %(filename)s | %(lineno)d | %(funcName)s | %(message)s'
        datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: detailed
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    access_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: detailed
        filename: log/access.log
        backupCount: 30
        encoding: utf8
        when: D
        interval: 1
        delay: True

    exception_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: detailed
        filename: log/exception.log
        backupCount: 30
        encoding: utf8
        when: D
        interval: 1
        delay: True

loggers:
    access:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [console, access_file_handler]
        propagate: no

    exception:
        level: ERROR
        handlers: [console, exception_file_handler]
```

The problem is the date of the logs do not match with the date of  the file name. For example, here is the logs of access.log.2016-02-17.

```
2016-02-19 09:43:10 | 7065 | INFO | ...
2016-02-19 09:43:10 | 7065 | INFO | ...
...
2016-02-20 09:05:59 | 7065 | INFO | ...
2016-02-20 09:05:59 | 7065 | INFO | ...
...
```

Why is that? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Log rotation probably happens every day at the time you started the process.

Comment: What is the creation date of the log file?

Comment: I can't find the creation time. The date of access/modify/change time of file named access.log.2016-02-17 is 2016-02-20.

Comment: The creation date is important. It stores the first time the file was created

Comment: It seems Linux doesn't store creation time. I can only get access/modify/change time after `stat access.log.2016-02-17`.

Answer (score 4):

After reading the source code of TimedRotatingFileHandler, finally figured out what's going on.

The parameter of `when` should be `midnight`, not `D`. `midnight` means rotating at midnight. That's exactly what I want.

`D` means rotating after the interval of `interval` days. If the value of `interval` is 1, and the application starts at 10:00, then the rotating will happen at 10:00 after the next day. There will be two dates in the same log file. If you restart the application when 9:00 after the next day, rotating will delay until 9:00 after the day after the next day. There will be three dates in the same log file.

Answer (score 0):

You set delay=True in your configuration file.

> If delay is true, then file opening is deferred until the first call
>   to emit().

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

This means that the logfile is starting from the first log message.

There could be an issue that the file name is defined before the actual opening of the log file causing a mismatch between the file name and the dates in the log file

Comment: It's weird. The program has log every day, it called emit() every day. But the log wasn't rotated when emit() first called that day.

Comment: Try removing delay=True from your configuration file.